# How to Train model in which number of classes is equal to number of instances in particular image used for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

Suppose one classroom contains 40 students.

Then I trained model for all images of 40 students and then try to detect all 40 students in one picture.

But not getting good accuracy.

Why this is happing? Is any other measure criteria other than just measuring the accuracy of the model?

Comment: How much is your data? Also, what architecture did you use?

Comment: That would be a multilabel problem rather than multiclass. So probably you have the entire accuracy metric wrong if you didnt label your images properly.  If you have a preprocessing that is able to identify the 'faces' in the test image then you can perform multiclass recognition on each of the 'faces'.

Comment: If you have trained your model on pictures of a single face, you shouldn't expect it to work on different kinds of pictures. Your model will only work well on data similar to the training data that you used (provided it did work well there in the first place). The neural network does not "recognize faces" like a person, it recognizes patterns in particular examples of data, different data requires different patterns to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little improvement can be achieved through data augmentation. For every image (in your case, every student), you could say that an object rotated by 10 percent, is still the same object for the observer. The same goes for mirroring the image. By adding a couple of new data points this way, you would probably get better results.

Comment: I will try this. I think it will improve my accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I think its way of approach, which model you use for this assignment?
I'm not sure CNN is the best approach here.
Try this way - 
- You take each picture and encode his face, you can use Cascade filter to identify human face and then apply encoding on this rectangle.
- Each encoding you save.
- In a given human face identification rectangle you encode it and you check for distance between what you have in storage

Try this approach, I think you can get nice results.
You can use Face Recognition & opencv

I did somthing similar, you can check it out.
[link](https://github.com/vection/Face-Classification)

Comment: But do you think Cascade will better than CNN ?. Because I have to detect multiple faces.

Comment: In general not, but in your assignment you have very few images and you have to detect specific faces from one picture, so I would say that in this case Cascade can do this pretty fine.